# get input field value in submitted form

Tags: jquery, forms

I have multiple forms with the same name.

```
<form name="testFrom" action="/test" method="post">
<input name ="value1" type="text" />
<input type =submit/>
```

the same form is place in different areas of the page. When I click on submit.

I am calling below function

```
checkdata(form){

var value1 = $('form[name="testForm"] :input[type=text]').val();
alert(value1)
}
```

so the value1 is not consistent as we have other forms with the same name and fields values is returning from other forms.

How can get the value from submited form?

Answer (score 1):

put the form in a div and add a id, you can directly add ids to forms but in your case I understand that the forms are generated dynamically.

then you can simply use the selector to find the form inside a particular div.

with an id on form you can:

```
var value1 = $('form[name="testForm"] :input[type=text]').val();
```

with id on a div which contains the form.

```
var value1 = $('#form1 :input[type=text]').val();
```

Comment: It is not possible to add this form in div

Answer (score 0):

Since the method seems to receive the form as a param try

```
function checkdata(form) {
    var value1 = $(form).find('input[type=text]').val();
    alert(value1)
}
```

Comment: @sree how is `checkdata` called